# Passing parameters to a webapp2.RequestHandler object in python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Is there any way to pass parameters to a RequestHandler object when I create my WSGIApplication instance?

I mean

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/route1', Handler1),
    ('/route2', Handler2)
], debug=True)
```

Is it possible to pass some arguments to `MainHandler`, `Handler1` or `Handler2`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically, I want to use one single handler for several routes. I think your response is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also pass parameters through a configuration dictionary.

First you define a configuration:

```
import webapp2

config = {'foo': 'bar'}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=[
    (r'/', 'handlers.MyHandler'),
], config=config)
```

Then access it as you need. Inside a RequestHandler, for example:

```
import webapp2

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        foo = self.app.config.get('foo')
        self.response.write('foo value is %s' % foo)
```

From here: [webapp2 documentation](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/app.html#config)

Answer (score 8):

You pass "arguments" in the URL essentially.

```
class BlogArchiveHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.response.write('Hello, keyword arguments world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/<year:\d{4}>/<month:\d{2}>', handler=BlogArchiveHandler, name='blog-archive'),
])`
```

From here: [features](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/features.html)

The page at above link no longer exists. Equivalent doc can be found [here](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#extended-routes).

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I was looking for this.